# How can I create a bag page in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, cart, blocks

Currently I am using a custom page to build a checkout/cart page called bag.

I have this php inside it:

```
<?php
/**
 * Shopping cart template
 *
 * @see Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart
 */
?>


 <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table">
                <col width="1" />
                <col />
                <col width="1" />
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />

            <?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"></th>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Move to Wishlist') ?></span></th>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <th class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Unit Price') ?></span></th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
                        <th class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                        <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="50" class="a-right">
                            <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart') ?>" class="button btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('shopping-cart-table')</script>
        </fieldset>
    </form>


    <a href="/checkout/onepage" class="button">Go to checkout</a>
```

For some reason even though I have items on the cart nothing gets listed here at all.

Does anyone know why this would happen.

FYI: i have another page at checkout/cart that does the same but we need a /bag page as well.

Cheers

Comment: Do you want two different pages, with two different processes? Or two different process, but only one process?

Answer (score 2):

You can manage this by go to Catalog->URL Rewrite Management

Click to Add URL Rewrite

Select Create URL Rewrite: Custom

ID Path: checkout/cart

Request Path: bag

Target Path: checkout/cart

Redirect: No

Comment: Yes saw that but they still want checkout/cart as a url too

Comment: Isnt that the case? Cause you rewriting "bag" internally to "cart" but not "cart" to "bag". That was my thought?!?!

Comment: Yes that was my frustration but they need both as its part of the business values etc

Answer (score 2):

I had time to try it now:

When I configure the shop like I told in [the post before](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/8229/243), it works exactly as you want it

You can test it here in our demo-store:

https://www.centano-shop.de/checkout/cart/

https://www.centano-shop.de/bag/

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you just rename shopping cart - > bag?

Comment: They want to keep checkout/cart though.